# slideshow module where editor can upload images

Tags: 7

I am looking for a JQuery slideshow module, where an editor can upload images from Drupal, without having to go into the code or through ftp.  I imagine this module already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options, but I am rather fond of [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow)

It allows you to create a slideshow from a view. What is nice is this basically means the possibilities are endless. Plus, it allows your user to easily upload images, assuming of course you have created a content type they can use.